# Showing wrong number of videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the *YouTube API V3* for getting videos of a channel, but it returns the wrong number of videos. The channel has in total 11 videos, but when I do the call to the API, I get only 6 (or 7, I don't know the case) of them, also if I specify the **maxResults** parameter to 11 or higher.

How can I resolve this? Thanks. I didn't found any setting for this in my youtube account.

To demostrate it, the channel ID is: **UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ**

Comment: are the videos set to private?

Comment: No, they're public. You can see them here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ/videos

Comment: Post your code please and I will take a look later

Comment: This is the URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ&maxResults=13&order=date&key={MY KEY}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ&maxResults=13&order=date&key=[API_KEY]
```

I'm able to get the 11 videos you mentioned:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/HAvUl5A7ZOXUisEPHf47emX1hL0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 12,
  "resultsPerPage": 13
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/PgKUDIanQqJM06eGCdOcY1k8U2E\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "wgIGFp6LTpg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-27T09:00:41.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Trapianto di Cornea DALK",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wgIGFp6LTpg/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wgIGFp6LTpg/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wgIGFp6LTpg/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/iI_e3liC80z1dubSCRt-GMMglqU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "M48hn7bBof8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-27T08:57:31.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Cheratoprotesi di Boston",
    "description": "La cornea artificiale è l'ultima frontiera per la cura delle malattie della cornea. Ne esistono di diversi tipi: la piu utilizzata è la Cornea artificiale (cheratoprotesi) di ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M48hn7bBof8/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M48hn7bBof8/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M48hn7bBof8/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/0UZloLuYjiuCboAS78hx0Crez3E\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Y2I2ZLpKDc8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-26T14:50:09.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Intralase",
    "description": "Tecnologia laser a femtosecondi di Abbott Laboratories sulla quale si basa l'intervento LASIK.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y2I2ZLpKDc8/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y2I2ZLpKDc8/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y2I2ZLpKDc8/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/d8MMhw3T03DfFfUHMUUkSWuOPyI\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "SbhcbwTLX7c"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-26T14:26:30.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Trapianto di Cornea Endotelio DSAEK",
    "description": "Trapianto di endotelio della cornea (DSAEK) con iniettore NCI. Nuova tecnica di trapianto di cornea per pazienti con distrofia di Fuchs o edema della cornea ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SbhcbwTLX7c/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SbhcbwTLX7c/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SbhcbwTLX7c/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/Mb5mqYX17_L_9Y5t9FwSUcUhXI0\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "hKgget6QLMM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T14:18:26.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Cheratoprotesi di Boston: Trapianto di Cornea",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hKgget6QLMM/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hKgget6QLMM/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hKgget6QLMM/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/qWC6lNxyC2DanUqXZjh9hnCE6a0\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Zxe6N9gLYOk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T14:13:30.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Chirurgia Cataratta con lente Hi Tech",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zxe6N9gLYOk/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zxe6N9gLYOk/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zxe6N9gLYOk/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/4fEXZSXNyt6Er2llnk-Tq1-H3Xo\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "d-txNN-7LvE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T14:08:48.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Chirurgia Cheratocono con INTACTS - Chirurgia Live",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d-txNN-7LvE/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d-txNN-7LvE/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d-txNN-7LvE/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/EeTGCvw9RrGuPB3KDSzZR0iGMEA\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Imtlb7qmags"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T14:05:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Chirurgia Cheratocono con INTACTS - Animazione",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Imtlb7qmags/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Imtlb7qmags/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Imtlb7qmags/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/ssmNJT0LbRQRRlTGjJ-wbCNh5SM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "ryWlPp29kiI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T13:57:46.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Correzione Miopia, Ipermetropia e Cataratta con la lente Hi Tech",
    "description": "Correggere miopia, astigmatismo, presbiopia ed ipermetropia è possibile in un unico intervento grazie alla lente Hi-tech. Si tratta di un cristallino artificiale che ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ryWlPp29kiI/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ryWlPp29kiI/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ryWlPp29kiI/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/YHFCRZaoPNuTzlLHmOAWzyydvZw\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "RJmm40oaVwk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T13:52:07.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Chirurgia della Cataratta: novità",
    "description": "La più grande innovazione in chirurgia della cataratta è la lente Hi-Tech che permette di curare in un unico intervento miopia, astigmatismo, presbiopia e ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RJmm40oaVwk/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RJmm40oaVwk/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RJmm40oaVwk/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/rs7lh7958amlLisrvdxndE1neAc\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "4sfAlyiSA8s"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-25T08:35:34.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Lente Intraoculare Hi Tech",
    "description": "I difetti della vista: miopia, astigmatismo, presbiopia e ipermetropia si possono finalmente correggere con un unico intervento: la chirurgia con la lente Hi-Tech o ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4sfAlyiSA8s/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4sfAlyiSA8s/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4sfAlyiSA8s/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/NAW_LlewyAxUlC7o6lL1oQxW2VY\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-24T18:10:32.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ",
    "title": "Micro Chirurgia Oculare - dott. Federico Badalà",
    "description": "Il Dott. Federico Badalà dopo aver a lungo lavorato in USA è stato il primo chirurgo oculista italiano ad eseguire interventi innovativi nel campo della chirurgia ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lvWU6W_lntU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/yKCZSRHZcNI/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lvWU6W_lntU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/yKCZSRHZcNI/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lvWU6W_lntU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/yKCZSRHZcNI/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

For some strange reason, it doesn't work when I copy the URL you posted in the comments, but when I copy the channelId posted above and paste that in your URL, it works (even though it's the same ID, how strange...). Another way you could try to do this is to use [`playlistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) and provide your [uploads playlist ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads) (which you can get by calling [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and specifying `part=contentDetails`), which gives your uploaded videos in reverse chronological order.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUOjT220XvzZrX6LuZ6GnrGQ&maxResults=13&key=[API_KEY]
```

Comment: Thank you. For some strange reason, sometimes when I refresh the page, it shows all videos; the other times no. I don't know. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: No problem! It might just be the API acting up.